# how to choose which user php runs in?

Tags: php, linux

I want php to be able to read any file in all subfolders of a specific folder (I'm using Ubuntu 12.10). The php user (as returned by posix_geteuid and posix_getpwuid) is 'www-data'.

The permissions of one such file is "-rw-r--r--", the parent folders are all "drwxr--r--" or "drwxrwxr-x".

Since all R are turned on, wouldn't any user be able to read all these files? I don't want to change the owner of all files to 'www-data', how can I instead run php with the right user? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're running it under a webserver. You'll ALWAYS be running as the same userID as the webserver, unless you use something like suphp. plus, just having the files readable isn't enough. the parent containing directories have to be accessible to whatever user you want as well.

Comment: put www-data in the same group?

Comment: Well, everything is in the same computer. Why do I get "failed to open stream: Permission denied in..." when I try getimagesize()? What do I need to change?

Comment: How do I do that, @Loïc? I went into the user accounts configuration, but I can't add a user "www-data", it won't let the - hyphen in the name...

Comment: OK, the third R is the "others" read access. If all files/folders in the path have this third R enabled, WHY can't www-data read them?

Answer (score 0):

When I see your all right about files you are talking about I don't understand why user is a probleme. Every body should have right to read youre file. As Marc B says: you'll always use  the same userId, so.. Make sure this user can read files, or turn him into the owner files.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to linux... It seems I need to put the 'www-data' user in the right group. What group should it be, and how do I do that?

Comment: If you're new, you should learn something about the rights :http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/ .
I hope it will help you, and for the group you should use I don't kwow, look at the differents groups (which already exist), and look what rights they have.. 

Hope I help you! Good luck! And even if Linux is hard on the begginning, you'll see it's wonderfull.

Comment: Thank you. I like Linux, and already know a few things. I added the user 'www-data' to my group here (I used the "groups" command to find out). Then I reboot. But I keep getting the same message "failed to open stream: Permission denied". Why??

Comment: Did you use a LAMP server?

Comment: No, I don't use a LAMP server.

Comment: Can you explain me exactly what does that mean, or how do I do it, @SamaelStern? By the way, it's all running in a single machine.

Comment: Perhaps I need a x permission on the directory, not a r?

Comment: Try x permission (but it's weard, you don't need to execute the file..). Try the command : "chmod 777" on the files you need. You'll have all the rights.